# How can I evenly split up a pandas.DataFrame into n-groups?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, cross-validation

I need to perform n-fold (in my particular case, a 5-fold) cross validation on a dataset that I've stored in a pandas.DataFrame. My current way seems to rearrange the row labels;

```
spreadsheet1 = pd.ExcelFile("Testing dataset.xlsx") 
dataset = spreadsheet1.parse('Sheet1') 

data = 5 * [pd.DataFrame()]

i = 0
while(i  < len(dataset)):
    j = 0
    while(j < 5 and i < len(dataset)):
        data[j] = (data[j].append(dataset.iloc[i])).reset_index(drop = True)
        i += 1
        j += 1
```

How can I split my DataFrame efficiently/intelligently without tampering with the order of the columns?

Comment: Why not just use [`sklearn.model_selection.KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)?

Comment: @G. Anderson yes it absolutely does, thank you. I thought I did a pretty thorough search but I was wrong

Comment: @blacksite, I'm sure that does what I need but it's a little over my head

Comment: Seconding the suggestion by @blacksite, if you say you're already planning to do cross validation, it might be worth leanring more about sklearn given that they have built-in methods [already built for cross-val](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) that can be fitted directly on pandas dataframes without having to do the manual splitting yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.array_split` to break it up into a list of "evenly" sized DataFrames. You can shuffle too if you sample the full DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(-1,2), columns=['A', 'B'])
N = 5    

np.array_split(df, N)
#np.array_split(df.sample(frac=1), N)  # Shuffle and split
```

---

```
[   A  B
 0  0  1
 1  2  3
 2  4  5,
     A   B
 3   6   7
 4   8   9
 5  10  11,
     A   B
 6  12  13
 7  14  15,
     A   B
 8  16  17
 9  18  19,
      A   B
 10  20  21
 11  22  23]
```

Comment: thank you! Another commenter put a link that also answers my question so I made this post associate with the other, but i actually prefer your solution. While it requires numpy (what doesnt?), it's trivially easy and straightforward. Thanks again

Comment: @A.Salas yup, just be careful of the differences. np.array_split ensures the group sizes are as close as possible. So while the solutions in that dup give you 3 groups with 400/400/311 rows array_spit would give you 370/370/371 (which seems to be closer to what you want...)

Comment: even more reason for me to use your solution, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am still not sure why you want to do it in this way but here is a solution

```
df['fold'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, df.shape[0])
```

For example, your first fold is

```
df.loc[df['fold'] == 1]
```